# Find the indicated expectations and probabilities.

Tags: random-variables, lebesgue-measure, expected-value

Let $\Omega = (0,1], \mathcal{F} = \mathcal{B}(\Omega),P = \lambda$, where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure with random variables,
$$X_{n} := \sqrt{n}1_{\{\omega < 1/n\}}$$ 
$$Y_{n} := \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n\omega}}$$

Find:
a) $E(X_{n})$

b)$E(Y_{n})$

c)$P(X_{n}\geq10)$

d)$P(Y_{n}\geq10)$

e)$P(Y_{n}\geq X_{n})$

My approach so far,

a) Since, we have the indicator function
$$E(X_{n}) = E(\sqrt{n}1_{\{\omega < 1/n\}}) = \sqrt{n}E(1_{\{\omega < 1/n\}}) = \sqrt{n}P(\omega < 1/n) = \sqrt{n}/n = 1/\sqrt{n}.$$ Is the correct?

b)$$E(Y_{n}) = \int_{0}^{1}Y_{n}d\lambda(\omega) = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n\omega}}d\lambda(\omega) = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n\omega}}\lambda(d\omega) = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n\omega}} d\omega = 1/\sqrt{n}.$$

Is this correct? I have used $\lambda(d\omega) = d\omega$ because $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure.

c) $P(X_{n}\geq10)$ = $P(\sqrt{n}1_{\{\omega < 1/n\}}\geq10) = P(1_{\{\omega < 1/n\}}\geq10/\sqrt{n}) = ?.$ How do I go about it from here? Do I take the intersection of both the events?

d) $P(Y_{n}\geq10)$ = $P\Big(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n\omega}}\geq10\Big) = P\Big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\omega}} \geq 20\sqrt{n} \Big) = P\Big({\sqrt{\omega}} \geq \frac{1}{20\sqrt{n}}\Big) = P\Big(\omega \leq \frac{1}{400n} \Big) = \frac{1}{400n}.$ Is this correct?

e) $P(Y_{n}\geq X_{n}) = P(Y_{n} - X_{n}\geq 0) = ?$ I tried replacing $X_{n}$ and $Y_{n}$ with what's given in the question but could not go further.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: $X_n = \sqrt{n}$ with probability $\frac{1}{n}$ and $0$ otherwise. (a),(b) are correct. For (c) note, the probability will be either $0$ or $\frac{1}{n}$ depending on the value of $n$ (why?). And for (e) I would condition on the value of $X_n$, that is $\mathbb P(Y_n \ge X_n) = \mathbb P(Y_n \ge X_n | X_n = 0)\mathbb P(X_n = 0) + \mathbb P(Y_n \ge X_n | X_n = \sqrt{n})\mathbb P(X_n = \sqrt{n})$
EDIT: I've just noticed, u swapped $\ge$ with $\le$ in (d). That is, your result should be $\mathbb P( \omega \ge \frac{1}{400n} ) = 1 - \frac{1}{400n}$

Comment: Because depending on the value of n, we get different values that X can take. For example, up until n=100, $P(X_{n} \geq 10)=0$. From n=100 onwards, $P(X_{n} \geq 10)=1/n$. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly. And for (e) answer is $\mathbb P(Y_n \ge 0 \cap X_n = 0) + \mathbb P(Y_n \ge \sqrt{n} \cap X_n = \sqrt{n}) = \mathbb P( \{ \omega \in \Omega : \omega < \frac{1}{n} \}) + \mathbb P( \{ \omega \in \Omega : \omega \ge \frac{1}{n} \wedge \omega \le \frac{1}{2n}) = \frac{1}{n} + 0 = \frac{1}{n}$

Comment: @DominikKutek Got it. Thank you so much.